# modifying the vertical gabs between two elements in JList

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

this is a part of my code :

```
    listNumber1 = new JList();
    listNumber1.setListData(numbers);
    listNumber1.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    scroll1 = new JScrollPane(listNumber1);
    scroll1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,100));


    listOperations = new JList();
    listOperations.setListData(operations);
    listOperations.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    scroll2 = new JScrollPane(listOperations);
    scroll2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,100));

    listNumber2 = new JList();
    listNumber2.setListData(numbers);
    listNumber2.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    scroll3 = new JScrollPane(listNumber2);
    scroll3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,100));
```

[image: example]

**My Question :**
How to increase the vertical **gabs** between **(+)**, **(-)**  and   **(*)**   to be like the middle JList in the picture

Comment: what is the issue with gaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the light of camickr answer :

To increase a cell height :

```
 list.setFixedCellHeight(Hight );
```

for the Question **Height = 30** will give a good result :

```
 listOperations.setFixedCellHeight(30);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try overriding the `getFixedCellHeight()` to return the height of the JList / 3.

Comment: The SSCCE future is now assured at Java Ranch.  It is also significantly smaller (50% less download/40% less page downs).  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use empty strings for the gaps. This is not ideal because if the user selects them, you will have to do nothing or display a user-friendly error, but it will work.

Comment: As you said ,It's not that ideal solution